How much will repeating a measure before an intervention improve my statistical power?
I am measuring the PHQ-9 depression scale in a study at baseline and four-week follow-up in an intervention study with several thousand participants.
I am considering measuring it an additional time, a few days before baseline, to improve the study's statistical power. However, I'm not sure how much of a difference in power it would make. The test-retest reliability for the PHQ-9 is supposedly excellent, around r=0.85 if re-tested within a few days. Is it worth some effort to measure once more, or not?
Based on Goulet & Cousineau (2019), I'm guessing the correlation is too high for it to make much difference at all, but the big sample size is making me reconsider a bit.

Goulet, M. A., & Cousineau, D. (2019). The power of replicated
measures to increase statistical power. Advances in Methods and
Practices in Psychological Science, 2(3), 199-213.

